# grunt to build dynamic jade pages

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, pug, kraken.js

I want to use grunt to build my node.js project (based on Kraken.js, but I've replaced dust with jade). I've installed `grunt-contrib-jade`. For jade files that contain no server side state this all works nicely and I get the HTML files output. However, where I have .jade files that contain logic and render server-side state it all goes wrong. For example, if I have `h1 #{x.y}` in my file the grunt output is `cannot read property y of undefined`. This makes complete sense as `x` is only defined at runtime.

So I'm now wondering do I just ignore my jade files in the grunt build and let the server process them all at runtime, or is there some alternative that I'm missing to 'pre-process' my .jade files to speed up execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting an answer of mine ([Would it benefit to pre-compile jade templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22220839/would-it-benefit-to-pre-compile-jade-templates-on-production-in-express/22221261#22221261)):

> When Jade compiles the template, the template is cached. In production environment if you warm up the cache, then there is no need to pre-compile template. Even if you don't, the template will be cached after its first compilation.

**In short:** Compiling Jade template is useless. You'd better remove `grunt-contrib-jade`.