# Decrease First Byte Time with ExpressJS?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to figure out how to get this sped up some. Setting up a basic route that renders a template is responding ~280ms over ping. If I put a log message in the handler, it shows up almost instantly upon browser refresh, but the actual response takes 300ms to send back.

Is there some setting that could be influencing this?

This is my route:

```
app.get '*', (req, res) ->
    if !req.user
        return res.redirect('/login')
    res.render 'index'
```

This is all my middleware and server config:

```
express = require 'express'
compression = require 'compression'
cookieParser = require 'cookie-parser'
bodyParser = require 'body-parser'
session = require 'express-session'
morgan = require 'morgan'
winston = require 'winston'
settings = require './settings'
user = require './user'

passport = require 'passport'
GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy
# Used for persisting sessions only
RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session)

logger = new winston.Logger({
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console(),
        new winston.transports.File({filename: settings.PROJECT_DIR + 'logs.log'})
    ]
})

app = express()

# Misc
app.use morgan('dev')

# Express settings
app.set 'views', settings.PROJECT_DIR + 'views'
app.set 'view engine', 'jade'

oneDay = 86400000
app.use express.static(settings.PROJECT_DIR + "public", {maxAge: oneDay})
app.use compression()

# Parsers
app.use cookieParser('redacted')
app.use bodyParser()

# Users
app.use session
    secret: 'redacted'
    store: new RedisStore
    resave: false
    saveUninitialized: true
    cookie: {maxAge: 2592000000}

app.use passport.initialize()
app.use passport.session()

passport.use new GoogleStrategy
    clientID: 'redacted',
    clientSecret: 'redacted',
    callbackURL: "redacted"
    , (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) ->
        user.findOrCreate profile, (err, user) ->
            return done(err, user)

passport.serializeUser (user, done) ->
    done(null, user.id)

passport.deserializeUser (id, done) ->
    user.findById id, (err, user) ->
        done(err, user);

server = require('http').createServer app
routes = require('./routes') app

server.listen(9100)
```

I have an nginx reverse proxy in front of the server, but visiting directly by ip and port shows no change.

Comment: Need to see some code - express settings, middleware mounted on the route, etc..

Comment: Added a lot of extra info

Comment: See what happens when you take off your auth middleware. If it's that then you at least have some knowledge about where your bottleneck is located. I don't know how much data is in your database for user info but the hashing might take a while for the first time your user logs in.

Comment: Also try setting `$NODE_ENV` to `production` to enable [view caching](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.render) in Express (or enable it manually).

Comment: Oi, it was setting production mode that did it. Want to add that as an answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Would it benefit to pre-compile jade templates on production in express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22220839/would-it-benefit-to-pre-compile-jade-templates-on-production-in-express)